# Heroku app runs locally but crushes remotely

Tags: java, maven, heroku, procfile

Just studying so thanks in advance for understanding.

I built some training Java SpringBoot project. It's a simple websocket chat, but that's no matter. It successfully runs locally via Eclipse or Maven (with no Eclipse).

Now my task is to run it in web using Heroku. I deployed it in Heroku using GitHub. App runs successfully via `heroku local`, but in web it crushes and I dont know why. My procfile:

`web: java -jar target/testweb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

Heroku logs:

```
2020-05-13T17:58:33.479226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-13T17:58:41.066644+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-13T17:58:41.071889+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079324+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079416+00:00 app[web.1]: .   ____          _            __ _ _
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079514+00:00 app[web.1]: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079610+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079706+00:00 app[web.1]: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079799+00:00 app[web.1]: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2020-05-13T17:58:43.079919+00:00 app[web.1]: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2020-05-13T17:58:43.081637+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.3.RELEASE)
2020-05-13T17:58:43.081700+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-13T17:58:43.470225+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:43.463  INFO 4 --- [           main] testweb3.controller.Application          : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 2822987a-4c88-4248-ae00-4b0832ebd7c2 with PID 4 (/app/target/testweb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war started by u59116 in /app)
2020-05-13T17:58:43.472319+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:43.472  INFO 4 --- [           main] testweb3.controller.Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-13T17:58:46.129477+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:46.129  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2020-05-13T17:58:46.144819+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:46.144  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-13T17:58:46.145182+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:46.145  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-05-13T17:58:47.987053+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:47.986  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-05-13T17:58:48.140150+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.139  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-13T17:58:48.140335+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.140  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4467 ms
2020-05-13T17:58:48.359123+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.358  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2020-05-13T17:58:48.364258+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.364  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2020-05-13T17:58:48.372881+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.372  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2020-05-13T17:58:48.456122+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:48.455  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2020-05-13T17:58:50.143529+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:50.143  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2020-05-13T17:58:50.143807+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:50.143  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
2020-05-13T17:58:50.145205+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:50.145  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2020-05-13T17:58:50.209917+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:50.209  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 33163 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-13T17:58:50.221351+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:58:50.221  INFO 4 --- [           main] testweb3.controller.Application          : Started Application in 8.005 seconds (JVM running for 9.15)
2020-05-13T17:59:48.454213+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-13 17:59:48.453  INFO 4 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2020-05-13T18:00:09.026314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-13T18:18:54.299951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chat-vu.herokuapp.com request_id=5c30f183-f455-4760-a3b0-3c1b5d8835ae fwd="31.173.30.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-13T18:18:55.362479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chat-vu.herokuapp.com request_id=848e21a6-86f7-42b8-be18-01d79d96d6c0 fwd="31.173.30.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-13T18:18:58.408258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chat-vu.herokuapp.com request_id=ed6b1b54-5d8c-4b43-acb1-8314ad965a20 fwd="31.173.30.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-05-13T18:18:59.426224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=chat-vu.herokuapp.com request_id=182cbc27-56c0-4961-9deb-9518e1ca86d2 fwd="31.173.30.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-13T18:19:00.070337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chat-vu.herokuapp.com request_id=7c9c4519-3ec2-42bd-a83b-f6eb3c1ea8f2 fwd="31.173.30.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Project on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/freshnoon/testweb3).

Please help :)

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running your application on the port given by Heroku via the `$PORT` environment variable. Change your `Procfile` contents to:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/testweb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

to fix your problem. You can read more about the topic here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications#spring-boot